# C: How to correct this segfault

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, 2d

The following code is showing segfault( I don't know why?)
The input was within limits of the 2d array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int ar[10000][10000],n,m,i,j;

    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            ar[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&ar[1][i]);
    }
    for(i=2;i<=m;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(j!=n)
            {
                ar[i][j]=ar[i-1][j]^ar[i-1][j+1];
            }
            else
            {
                ar[i][j]=ar[i-1][j]^ar[i-1][1];
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",ar[m-1][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a 100M array on the stack?

Comment: You're creating a `10000 * 10000` `int` array on stack, that's why. Create this array using `malloc` on heap, and you'll probably not have this segfault anymore.

Comment: Your loops are wrong. Arrays in C are from zero to `n-1`. So your loops should be `for (i=0;i<m;i++)` etc.

Comment: the limiting of array size helped actually! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Define your array as gloabal variable, outside the main. Global variables are located in the data segment and local variables are in the stack, so maybe here the stack overflows